# Can we create tag synonyms for [écriture-inclusive]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Lately I've been checking tags on French SE to see if everything was being used and if we needed to do a cleanup.

I saw the `[écriture-inclusive]` tag, which is relevant and might be used more and more in the following years as this subject becomes bigger and bigger in French language. Therefore, I suggest the creation of two synonym tags:

- `[ecriture-inclusive]` (without the accent, which is done with some other tags already).
- `[inclusive-writing]` (which appears to be the equivalent term in English).

---

En ce moment, je regarde les tags sur French SE pour voir s'ils sont tous utilisés et si un nettoyage est nécessaire.

J'ai vu le tag `[écriture-inclusive]`, qui est pertinent et risque d'être de plus en plus utilisé à mesure que ce sujet devient plus important dans la langue française. Par conséquent, je suggère la création de deux tags synonymes :

- `[ecriture-inclusive]` (sans l'accent, une pratique qui existe déjà avec d'autres tags).
- `[inclusive-writing]` (qui semble être l'équivalent anglais, bien que cette problématique n'existe pas dans la langue anglaise).

Comment: Done. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: *which appears to be the equivalent term in English*, English do have a related problem, though, and it made quite a lot of noise in SE code of conduct recently: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336364/279135

Comment: Yes, there is a debate in English about pronouns. The discussion on SE is more oriented around avoiding misgendering people and using pronouns they are more comfortable with (there is no real equivalent of *inclusive writing* in English, but neutral pronouns sure are the closest thing from it). :)